# Callback when VLC done on command line

Tags: python, command-line, vlc

I need to make VLC download then play songs.  I'm planning on using the `os.popen` to issue commands to the VLC command line (I'm having some problems getting the python binding working...).  My question is, is there any callback that I can get when VLC is done downloading so that I can know to start streaming?

Comment: why don't you download yourself and start playback with vlc once you know that the download is finished? I don't think that vlc provides any callback

Comment: I want to do the download programatically using one of the VLC features.  Because the audio I am trying to download is not easy to get with a wget or urllib2 type thing

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off doing the download yourself, but if you really want to do this, you might be able to combine http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/notify-when-up2.html with a sniffer like tshark or tcpdump.

Or...  You could modify vlc.  ^_^

Answer (score 0):

To close VLC after any actions append `vlc://quit` to your command line